# How to put multiple components in a single cell of h:panelGrid

Tags: jsf-2, panelgrid

I would like to create a `<h:panelGrid>` with one column.
However in one row I would like to fit two components together in one cell.

E.g.

```
<h:panelGrid columns="1">
     <h:outputText value="ROW 1 A"/>
     <h:outputText value="ROW 1 B"/>

     <h:outputText value="ROW 2"/>
</h:panelGrid>
```

Should end up in two rows

> ROW 1 A ROW 1 B
>   ROW 2

However, it currently ends up as

> ROW 1 A
>   ROW 1 B
>   ROW 2

How to put multiple components in a single cell of `<h:panelGrid>`?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

how about wrapping with single `<h:panelGroup>`

```
<h:panelGroup>
    <h:outputText value="ROW1 A"/>
    <h:outputText value="ROW 1 B"/>
</h:panelGroup>
```

Answer (score 3):

Wrap them in a `<h:panelGroup>`. [Here is an example](http://www.jsftoolbox.com/documentation/help/12-TagReference/html/h_panelGroup.html).